# Convert an unbound value to a bound value using an algorithm?

Tags: c, math

I have a device driver that uses the following algorithm to convert a value received from a sensor (no bound range) to a different value (bound range).

The sensor's values are usually within the 0-200 range but can exceed it, the maximum being about 4000 (this only happens when you use the sensor in an extreme way). I basically need a function that can do the following but without the giant `if` so it is more flexible.

**It needs to take in the value, the step (in this case 20.0f) and the max output (in this case 10).**

```
/* disregard the floating point numbers, I can cast them to int */
if (value <= 20.0f)
    return 0;
else if (value <= 40.0f)
    return 1;
else if (value <= 60.0f)
    return 2;
else if (value <= 80.0f)
    return 3;
else if (value <= 100.0f)
    return 4;
else if (value <= 120.0f)
    return 5;
else if (value <= 140.0f)
    return 6;
else if (value <= 160.0f)
    return 7;
else if (value <= 180.0f)
    return 8;
else if (value <= 190.0f)
    return 9;
else if (value >= 200.0f)
    return 10;

return 0;
```

Comment: ok, what happens to values in the range (190.0, 200.0) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int step(double value, int step, int maximum) { 
    return min(int(value / step), maximum);
}
```

Edit: As @DSM noted, this has a fencepost error, and should be something like:

```
int step(double value, int step, int maximum) { 
    return min(int((value-1) / step), maximum);
}
```

Comment: And note the function/formula can be anything, so you'll be as "flexible" as mathematics allows you to be.

Comment: +1 for general solution. You can also throw in a minimum parameter and do a max(minimum, min(...))

Comment: Almost certainly this doesn't matter, but this gives different answers at the transitions: the original function was 0 at 20.0, and the step function is 1, etc.  [And I'm not sure what's intended for values 190 < value < 200, but I'm assuming they're meant to give 10.]

Comment: @DSM: Oops -- you're quite right. I hadn't noticed that he was using `<=` instead of `<`.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have `min`, it looks like you want

```
min(0, (int)((min(220, value) - 20) / 20))
```

(Edited, sorry for the earlier min/max confusion!)

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
struct temp_thresholds {                                                                                                                                                                   
        float upper_bound;                                                                                                                                                                 
        int   ret_val;                                                                                                                                                                     
} thresholds = {                                                                                                                                                                           
        {  20.0f,     0},                                                                                                                                                                  
        {  40.0f,     1},                                                                                                                                                                  
        {  80.0f,     2},                                                                                                                                                                  
        // ..                                                                                                                                                                              
        { 190.0f,     9},                                                                                                                                                                  
        { 200.0f,     0}, // strange, and doesn't quite match your code                                                                                                                   
        { MAX_FLOAT, 10}, // find a constant like this                                                                                                                                     
};                                                                                                                                                                                         

int foo(float value)                                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                                          
        // if the table were big enough, you could do binary search                                                                                                                        
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof thresholds / sizeof thresholds[0]; ++i)                                                                                                                 
                if (value <= thresholds[i].upper_bound)                                                                                                                                    
                        return thresholds[i].ret_value;                                                                                                                                    
        assert(0);                                                                                                                                                                         
        return 0;                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, given the equal step sizes (I didn't read closely), then the math approach is better.

Comment: yeah, math is always better until someone makes the requirements a little more arbitrary ;-)